# Perl- segregate text file using search pattern and automatic emailing the attachment

Tags: perl, email

I have a a text file. I have segregated this using a small search pattern algorithm and i am getting the expected output

```
chomp(@ARGV);

if (@ARGV != 2)
 {

    print "Please Pass two parameters\n";
    print "Usage: \n\t $0 <Filename> <pattern>\n"; 
    exit;
}

$File_name     = $ARGV[0];
$res_File_name = $File_name . "\.result\.txt";
$Pattern       = $ARGV[1]; chomp($Pattern);

open(FD,"$File_name")      or die("File $File_name could not be opened\n");
open(WFD,">$res_File_name") or die("File $res_File_name could not be opened\n");

while(<FD>) 
{

    print WFD $_ if(/$Pattern/);
}

close(FD);
close(WFD);
```

but when the search is completed i am extracting only those pattern in a text file and placing it in my local drive. Instead i need to attach that text file in an email and need to sent it across. For this i am using office 365 were it shows email was sent successful, but i am not  receiving any email with the attachment

use MIME::Lite;

```
use Net::SMTP;
 use Mail::Sendmail1;
  use Net::SMTP::TLS; 
 #use strict;
if (@ARGV != 2)
 {

    print "Please Pass two parameters\n";
    print "Usage: \n\t $0 <Filename> <pattern>\n"; 
    exit;
}


$File_name     = $ARGV[0];
$res_File_name = $File_name . "\.result\.txt";
$Pattern       = $ARGV[1]; chomp($Pattern);

open(FD,"$File_name")      or die("File $File_name could not be opened\n");
open(WFD,">$res_File_name") or die("File $res_File_name could not be opened\n");

while(<FD>) 
{
 print WFD $_ if(/$Pattern/);






}
$to = 'xx@xx.com';
#$cc = 'xx@xx.com';
$from = 'xx@xx.com';
$subject = 'Test Email';
$message = 'This is test email sent by Perl Script';
open (txt.result.txt, '<', $res_File_name) or die "Failed to open $log_file: $!";
 @log_contents = <txt.result.txt>;
close txt.result.txt;
push @body, @log_contents;
 #open MAIL, '|C:\Perl\site\lib\Mail\Sendmail1 -t' or die "Failed to send mail: $!";
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                 From     => $from,
                 To       => $to,
                 #Cc       => $cc,
                 Subject  => $subject,
                 Type     => 'multipart/mixed'
                 );
                 #print MAIL "To: ${to}\n";
#print MAIL "From: ${from}\n";
#print MAIL "Subject: ${subject}\n\n";

# email body
#print MAIL @body;



# Add your text message.
$msg->attach(Type         => 'result.txt',
             Data         => $message
            ); 
            #$msg->send;
            #attach=( "Agent.txt.result.txt" )
    close(FD);
               close(WFD);      

    #close MAIL;
print "Email sent successfully.\n";     

exit;


#print "Email Sent Successfully\n";





    Help me on how i can achieve this.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo: `use Mail::Sendmail1` should be `Mail::Sendmail` (without "1"). But using `MIME::Lite` doesn't need `Mail::Sendmail`.

I recommend that you use other modules in order to send mail, like [Email::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Simple)

Comment: Yes, i modified the perl module and renamed it has sendmail1. Whatever it is this method is going to communicate with sendmail1 which is declared in namespace and oither part of script